# How create subdomain in IIS on Windows 2008 Azure VM?

Tags: azure, windows-server-2008-r2, azure-virtual-machine

My actions

1. Add Web Site... in IIS and set port 81
2. Try browse `http://localhost:81/` - is good.
3. Adds end point to 81 port
4. Try browse `http://myserver.cloudapp.net:81/` - is bad  (net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT).

Why?

UPD: myserver.cloudapp.net:80 - Default Web Site is visible

myserver.cloudapp.net:81 - My second Web Site is NOT visible

Second site binding is

Type: http; Port: 81; IP Address: *

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you [bound the IIS website to all addresses](http://blogs.technet.com/b/chrad/archive/2010/01/24/understanding-iis-bindings-websites-virtual-directories-and-lastly-application-pools.aspx) and not only localhost, and to default(*) [host headers](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753195%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)? Eventually you may want to add `myserver.cloudapp.net` as a host header to the site bindings.

**UPDATE**

And, of course you have to allow incoming Port 81 on the local VM Firewall settings.